# Span cvcolumns horizontally over entire page

Tags: moderncv, columns

How can I span the `cvcolumn` items over the entire page not only the column? I attached a `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % 'casual' 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{orange}  % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage{lipsum}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{A}{AAAA}
\title{curriculum vit\ae{}}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Computer Skills}
\cvitem{\LaTeX{}}{\lipsum[1]}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
    \cvcolumn{Boss}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
    \cvcolumn{Boss}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
    \cvcolumn{Boss}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
    \cvcolumn{Boss}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last you have two possibilities:

1. Use environment `cvcolumns` but add only three bosses per line like here:

   ```
   \begin{cvcolumns}
     \cvcolumn{Boss1}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
     \cvcolumn{Boss2}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
     \cvcolumn{Boss3}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
   \end{cvcolumns}
   \begin{cvcolumns}
     \cvcolumn{Boss4}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
     \cvcolumn{Boss5}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
   % \cvcolumn{Boss6}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
   \end{cvcolumns}
   ```
2. Add a tabular spanning the complete textwidth instead only the linewidth of the second column of the cv like the following:

   ```
   \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{4.5cm}p{4.5cm}p{4.0cm}}%{llll}
   {\color{color1}Boss1}             
     & {\color{color1}Boss2}  
     & {\color{color1}Boss3}  
     & {\color{color1}Boss4}  \\
   B BBBB                            
     & B BBBB 
     & B BBBB 
     & B BBBB \\
   \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com 
     & \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com 
     & \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com 
     & \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com \\
   \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx            
     & \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx  
     & \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx  
     & \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx  \\
   \end{tabular}
   ```

   Change the length of `p{4.5cm}` to values you need or simply try `l` instead. That depends on the length of your given email addresses ...

With the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1, body 1
\moderncvcolor{orange}  % 
\usepackage{lipsum}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.8,
  showframe % <==================== to visualize typing area and margins
]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{A}{AAAA}
\title{curriculum vit\ae{}}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Computer Skills}
\cvitem{\LaTeX{}}{\lipsum[1]}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
    \cvcolumn{Boss1}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
    \cvcolumn{Boss2}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
    \cvcolumn{Boss3}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
\end{cvcolumns}
\begin{cvcolumns}
    \cvcolumn{Boss4}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
    \cvcolumn{Boss5}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
%   \cvcolumn{Boss6}{B BBBB\\ \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com\\ \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx}
\end{cvcolumns}

\begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{4.5cm}p{4.5cm}p{4.0cm}}%{llll}
{\color{color1}Boss1}             
  & {\color{color1}Boss2}  
  & {\color{color1}Boss3}  
  & {\color{color1}Boss4}  \\
B BBBB                            
  & B BBBB 
  & B BBBB 
  & B BBBB \\
\emailsymbol longaddress@long.com 
  & \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com 
  & \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com 
  & \emailsymbol longaddress@long.com \\
\phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx            
  & \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx  
  & \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx  
  & \phonesymbol xxxxxxxxx  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting page:

[image: resulting page]

Comment: Thanks I was going for the second one in the end, even though its a bit manual.